# ESP32 power latch circuit react on low and high (reed switch)

Tags: power, low-power, esp32, latch

I am currently building a door sensor with an ESP32 and a reed switch.

My code is working with the deep sleep functionalities of the ESP32. With its help I can detect a falling/rising edge and wake the ESP32 up.

I am considering to save a lot more power and I want to use some sort of power latch circuit. The problem is, I don't know how to react to both events (closing and opening) of the reed switch. All the examples that I found react to the press of a button -> execute something -> shut itself down. But I want my system to react to a press of a button and also to the release of it.

Can any of you help me?

Comment: You can create a simple low power circuit that produces a logic 1 pulse when the switch opens or closes. That should help maybe?

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for your fast answer. How would i design a circuit with this functionaltiy?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ESP32 Technical Reference Manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf), chapter 4, the GPIOs have a wide selection of interrupt triggers.

Have a look at the *GPIO_PINn_REG* register:
[image]

Specifically the *GPIO_PINn_INT_TYPE* bits:
[image]

All you need to do is change the interrupt type to `GPIO_PINn_INT_TYPE = 3` (any edge trigger). This will allow both edges to wake the ESP32 from the sleep state.

Comment: Thank you for just suggestion, but i do have this one implemented. The Problem is I need to safe even more power. So I though of some kind of power latch circuit would be appropiate

Comment: In your comment above you ask a totally different question. I answered the question _"The Problem is, I don't know how to react on both events (closing and opening) [..] I want my system to react on a press of a button and on the release of it. Can any of you help me?"_

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. With the sentence "My code is at the moment working with the deep sleep functionalities of the ESP32" my intention was to say that I am already using deep sleep with the falling/rising edge technique. If I didn't already have that your answer would be perfect. I will edit my question now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the power latch circuit you refer to is similar to the below circuit. It completely powers off the ESP32. I can recommend such a setup as the ESP32 consumes too much power in deep sleep to have it powered from a battery for weeks. If that's not a requirement, deep sleep will also work.

In the below circuit, the ESP32 has to keep the *GPIO* input high after the short external trigger until it has done its work. I've found that this is a challenge. The ESP32 takes quite long to "boot" and power can already be off before it reaches the start of the regular firmware to set the GPIO. The solution was to use [custom bootloader](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-guides/bootloader.html#custom-bootloader). This is available in recent ESP-IDF version.

As for the sensors: In order to trigger it for both opening and closing, you could position the reed switch (for the power latch) such that it is near the door's *closed* position but not actuated when in the closed position.

In order to distinguish between the closed and open position, you might need to fit a second reed switch in the closed position. It would be wired directly to the ESP32 (instead of the power latch circuit).

The down side is of course that if the door was to remain in the position where the reed switch is actuated, the ESP32 will not power off and the battery will drain within hours.

[image: power latch schematic]

For this circuit, the battery is connected to VIN and GND. The ESP32 is powered from VCC and GND. The reed switch is connected to TRIG. GPIO is connected to a GPIO on the ESP32. The additional connector in the top left can be ignored.

Comment: That was a really detailed explanation. This should work and I will try it. But isnt their any other simpler method without the downside of the esp32 draining the whole battery when staying in an unintentional position